# Не могу повторно запустить функцию

Tags: javascript, html

Возник такой вопрос. В коде, прикрепленном ниже, содержится мини-игра. Её смысл состоит в том, чтобы кликать на падающие квадраты. Но при клике на квадрат новый квадрат не появляется, а продолжает движение с места, где был сделан клик. Что нужно исправить в коде, чтобы после клика по квадрату новый квадрат появлялся сверху?

```js
var start = document.getElementById('start');
var score = document.getElementById('score');
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var squarePosition_x = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 600);
var squarePosition_y = 0;
var stoping;
var points = 0;


function drawFrame() {

 // Очистить холст
 context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 
 // Вызываем метод beginPath(), чтобы убедиться,
 // что мы не рисуем часть уже нарисованного содержимого холста
 context.beginPath();

 
 context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.fillRect(squarePosition_x, squarePosition_y, 40, 40);
 
 // Перемещаем квадрат вниз на 1 пиксел (где он будет 
 // прорисован в следующем кадре)
 squarePosition_y += 1;

 stoping = requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);

}

start.addEventListener('click', drawFrame);

canvas.onmousedown = function canvasClick (e){

  var clickX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    var clickY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;

     // Проверка попадания
     if ((clickX > (squarePosition_x)) && (clickX < (squarePosition_x + 40)))
      {
         if ((clickY > (squarePosition_y)) && (clickY < (squarePosition_y + 40)))
          {
        
            cancelAnimationFrame(stoping);
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            context.beginPath();
            points++;
            score.innerHTML = points;
            setTimeout("drawFrame()", 1000);
            return;
          }
      }
 }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title> Qualium Systems Javascript test task </title>
    <style>
      canvas {
        background: black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <button id="start"> Start </button>
      <button onClick="stop()"> Stop </button>
      <span> Score: <span id="score"> 0 </span> </span>
    </div>
    <canvas width="640" height="480" id="canvas"></canvas>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script> 
</html>
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

после клика на квадрат, нужно сбрасывать значения переменных `squarePosition_x` и `squarePosition_y`

```js
var start = document.getElementById('start');
var score = document.getElementById('score');
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var squarePosition_x = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 600);
var squarePosition_y = 0;
var stoping;
var points = 0;


function drawFrame() {

  // Очистить холст
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Вызываем метод beginPath(), чтобы убедиться,
  // что мы не рисуем часть уже нарисованного содержимого холста
  context.beginPath();


  context.fillStyle = "red";
  context.fillRect(squarePosition_x, squarePosition_y, 40, 40);

  // Перемещаем квадрат вниз на 1 пиксел (где он будет 
  // прорисован в следующем кадре)
  squarePosition_y += 1;

  stoping = requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);

}

start.addEventListener('click', drawFrame);

canvas.onmousedown = function canvasClick(e) {

  var clickX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  var clickY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;

  // Проверка попадания
  if ((clickX > (squarePosition_x)) && (clickX < (squarePosition_x + 40))) {
    if ((clickY > (squarePosition_y)) && (clickY < (squarePosition_y + 40))) {

      cancelAnimationFrame(stoping);
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      context.beginPath();
      points++;
      score.innerHTML = points;
      squarePosition_x = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 600);  //здесь
      squarePosition_y = 0;   // и здесь
      setTimeout("drawFrame()", 1000);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title> Qualium Systems Javascript test task </title>
  <style>
    canvas {
      background: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button id="start"> Start </button>
    <button onClick="stop()"> Stop </button>
    <span> Score: <span id="score"> 0 </span> </span>
  </div>
  <canvas width="640" height="480" id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script>

</html>
```